# Rails 4 routing error for hash_for*(hash_for_path_name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

I am migrating my application from rails 2.3.18 to rails 4.0.0. My application works fine till rails 3.2.21. but when I migrate it from rails 3.2.21 to rails 4.0.0 it gives me error for hash_for* helper.

I got this error:

```
undefined method `hash_for_home_status_path' for #<#<Class:0xb636bb0c>:0xb636b0a8>
```

I found below method in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb  which is not available in rails 4 stable.

```
def hash_access_name(name, kind = :url)
   :"hash_for_#{name}_#{kind}"
end
```

Is there any patch for this removal or  any replacement to pass options hash in rails 4? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste more of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Review [Rails routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). You'll likely need to update some of your view files (removing the hash_for_* and replacing it with link_to or another method).

Comment: As hash_for_* returns hash with controller, action and some other useful information, I changed it with [recognize_path](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionDispatch/Routing/RouteSet/recognize_path) which works in the same way. It works for me.